# Physics Body with texture slows down fps

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a game where I have about 8 SKPhysicsBodies on the screen at one time, two of them are just simple squares and the is created with a texture. The Texture is nothing too complex, here's a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJKlz.jpg (black is transparent). The problem is that every time I spawn a PhysicsBody created with a texture the game freezes for few milliseconds which ruins the whole game, how could I increase the performance of the game? Here's how I create the physicsBody:

```
createObstacle1() {
let obstTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "obst1")
let obst1 = SKSpriteNode()
    obst1.size = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    obst1.color = player.color
    obst1.zPosition = 3
    obst1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: obstTexture1, size: obst1.size)
    obst1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    obst1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    obst1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    obst1.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    obst1.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    obst1.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    obst1.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    obst1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 3
    obst1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
    obst1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
    obst1.name = "obst1"

    self.addChild(obst1)
}
```

Comment: Anything thats transparent like glass for example causes expensive light/shadow calculations. Have you tried just using a white texture or a texture without transparency to see if there is a difference?

Comment: That physics body could be very complex,  depending on how apple handles texture to physics body,  that round curve could be a line for every 2 pixels

Comment: do not make your bodies during your update cycle, make them during your loading phase

Comment: So I just tried to it with textures without transparency and it's still lagging, I don't understand what the problem could be

Comment: What exactly do you mean KnightOfDragon?

Answer (score 0):

When and where you create the Obstacle? I guess as say Knight0fdragon that you must try to create out of the update event.
Silly question. You test on real device or simulator?

Salut,
Josep M

Comment: I test on a real device, but it doesn't matter I won't use textures anymore.

Comment: Are you spaw in the update? check the update differents events, should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too have experienced this, even with the seemingly simplest of shapes.  I now utilize `SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:` only in the rarest of circumstances because of the signifiant performance impact (as much as a 33% decrease in frame rate).